# Parameters in web part on right side instead of top

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services. I've created a report and then deployed it to my Sharepoint portal folder. I've added a SQL Server Reporting web part, but my report parameters are on the right side. I need them to be at top.

Has anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Sharepoint report web part always displays parameters to the right of the report. To my knowledge there is no way to change this behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: If you do find a way to do this, please post it as the answer to your question.